# What is the value of a polynomial form for a data structure, aka a Container

Tags: ct.category-theory, computer-science

Data structures like Lists and Trees are often referred to as Containers.  They can be given as monads and containers are polynomial functors.  The List monad is well known and can be given as a polynomial functor.  What do we gain by talking about data structures in terms of polynomial functors?  I guess what I am asking is how can we interpret the fact that data structures are polynomial functors?  I get how List is a monad, but the polynomial part is confusing.

Comment: I wonder if you may get a better response on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/?